# tvOS UICollectionView not able to change focus when creating View programmatically

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, tvos

I have a problem when creating a UICollectionView in Code as in comparison to creating the View in a Storyboard. In the programmatically created View, I am not able to change the focus, where as it works as intended in the storyboard version.

This is how I create the UICollectionView

```
class ChannelGridViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setup()
}

func setup() {
    let layout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 50, left: 50, bottom: 50, right: 50)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 350, height: 225)

    let grid = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    grid.dataSource = self
    grid.delegate = self
    grid.userInteractionEnabled = true
    grid.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    self.view.addSubview(grid)

}
```

The setup method is the only additional method I added to the programmatically part.

The rest of the methods are the following:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, canFocusItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = .greenColor()
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.clipsToBounds = false
    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldUpdateFocusInContext context: UICollectionViewFocusUpdateContext) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    if (context.nextFocusedView != nil) {
        coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({() -> Void in
            context.nextFocusedView!.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.05, 1.05)
            }, completion: { _ in })
    }
    if (context.previouslyFocusedView != nil) {
        coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({() -> Void in
            context.previouslyFocusedView!.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0)
            }, completion: { _ in })
    }
}
```

I hope you guys might help me, as I couldn't find that problem after an extended time of googling and stackoverflowing. 99% of the tutorials are about storyboards.

Thanks a lot,
Alex

Comment: This code works fine for me.

Comment: Is it a child view controller or some other complication?

Comment: Its is the main view controller. Really weird behaviour. Sorry, i didn't get a notification that a comment was posted